# Something like fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

Iam a physics student, I don't cover any proper course in harmonic analysis,
On the way of studying wavelets I make some guesses, But I don't know they are true or not.
They are marked as 1 and 2

1) $f (x)=\int db \psi (x-b) f (b)db $

If this

$\psi (x-b) $ is $e^{ik (x-b)} $  ,
$f (x)$ look like

2)$f (x) = \int db e^{i(x-b)k} f (b) $

Definitely this is not in the form of fourier transform

What I need to know is,
 can we decompose a function $f (x)$ as shown above?
Are this translated $e^{ikx}$ functions form a complete basis for the decomposition of a function?